# Streamlit Installation

Tags: python, streamlit

```
  cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\aabha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jnl3nkjb\pyarrow_b24498ed08994cca830adc29d8497039\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyarrow -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\aabha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe -DPython3_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\aabha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe -DPYARROW_CXXFLAGS= -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DPYARROW_BUILD_CUDA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_SUBSTRAIT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_FLIGHT=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GANDIVA=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ACERO=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_DATASET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_ORC=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_PARQUET_ENCRYPTION=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_GCS=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_S3=off -DPYARROW_BUILD_HDFS=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_ARROW_CPP=off -DPYARROW_BUNDLE_CYTHON_CPP=off -DPYARROW_GENERATE_COVERAGE=off -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release C:\Users\aabha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jnl3nkjb\pyarrow_b24498ed08994cca830adc29d8497039
  error: command 'cmake' failed: None
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

PS C:\Users\aabha> pip install streamlit

i did:
pip install streamlit

Comment: did you try reinstall/upgrade cmake and pyarrow https://pypi.org/project/cmake/ https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using python 3.12?

Streamlit doesn't support 3.12 yet because one of it's dependencies pyarrow  doesn't have wheels for 3.12 yet.

https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/7506